# Confused about setTranslationX() when translating FloatingActionButton on ViewPager scroll

Tags: android, android-viewpager, floating-action-button

I have some tabs in a `ViewPager`. Each tab except the last displays the `FloatingActionButton` at the bottom right corner. The last tab is supposed to display it in the bottom center, after translating it while this tab is being scrolled to. When scrolling away from this tab, the `FloatingActionButton` translates back into its bottom right position. I was implementing a solution, and was surprised to find that this, more or less, was all it took:

```
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            // One page away from last page
            if (position == mAdapter.getCount() - 2) {
                mFab.setTranslationX(positionOffsetPixels / -2f);
            }
        }
}
```

When I scroll to the last tab, we're translating the FAB to the left of its current position, because the argument passed to `setTranslationX()` is negative. Now, here's where I'm confused. When I scroll back one page, the FAB translates back to the right as desired--but how can this be? The argument to `setTranslationX()` is still negative. I expected the FAB to translate further left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're scrolling forward from the position `mAdapter.getCount() - 2`, the values of `positionOffsetPixels` will be increasing positive numbers and `positionOffsetPixels / -2f` will be increasing negative numbers, so the FAB will translate to the left, as expected.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener.html#onPageScrolled(int,%20float,%20int)) of `position`:

> Position index of the **first** page currently being displayed.

This means when scrolling back, the offset values will be relative to the page you're scrolling to, not to the page you're scrolling from.

When you're scrolling back from `mAdapter.getCount() - 1`, the value of `position` is `mAdapter.getCount() - 2` (this is the position you're scrolling to) and the values of `positionOffsetPixels` will be decreasing positive numbers going down to 0.

`0 / -2f == 0`, so eventually `mFab.setTranslationX(0)` will be called, returning the FAB to its original position.